# Select and join in same query from same table

Tags: mysql

I try to develop a mafia game. I store the users in a table, each user is able to set someone as testament. My problem is: x has ID1 and y who has ID2 sets x as testament (this will store ID1).

When x accesses his status page he should see all his stuff + the testament (y).

I'm newbie when I occur MySQL stuff, can someone explain me how to do this? Probably in future I will need to add more selects to that query, if someone would help me doing that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You do it with aliases

e.g

```
Select m.Name as Mum, c.Name as Child
From People m
inner join People c
On c.MumId = m.ID
```

Would pickout

```
Mum   Child
Irene Tony
```

from

```
People
ID Name MumID
1  Irene Null
2  Tony  1
```

Comment: I managed to do this using aliases and works good. Now I have another problem, I have a table with bank transfers where I keep the IDs. The script shows latest 20 transfers but I don't know how to get the usernames based on those IDs and have a performance friendly query

Comment: Ask another question then, need table structures. Your attempt at it would be good, Join Top20 to Transfers to Bank Account to User, presumably. Then look at performance.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` can be a testament to more than one other user, then it is best to use two queries to display the info:

```
SELECT \* FROM users WHERE id = ID1;  //This will display user x's data  
SELECT \* FROM users WHERE testament = ID1;   //This will list all users with testament = x
```

If it is 1-to-1 mapping (`x` can only be a testament for zero or one other user) then this works:

```
SELECT u1.\*, u2.\* FROM users u1 LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.testament WHERE u1.id = ID1;
```